# java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I was developing an app in Kotlin, with conect with API REST which works with XML data instead of JSON.

Im using SimpleXML library, an i'm getting the following error:

```
Process: es.paytef.payattable, PID: 13825
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=CheckEmp, required=true, type=void) on field 'CheckEmp' private java.lang.String es.paytef.payattable.data.response.GetCheckInfoResponseDTO$CheckInfo.CheckEmp for class es.paytef.payattable.data.response.GetCheckInfoResponseDTO$CheckInfo at line 4 at retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.convert(SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.java:45)
at retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.convert(SimpleXmlResponseBodyConverter.java:23)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Regarding my data model I define like this:

```
@Root(name = "GetCheckInfoResponse", strict = false)
class GetCheckInfoResponseDTO(
    @field:Element(name = "RespCode")
    @param:Element(name = "RespCode")
    var respCode: String,
    @field:Element(name = "RespText")
    @param:Element(name = "RespText")
    var respText: String,
    @field:ElementList(inline = true, name = "CheckInfo")
    @param:ElementList(inline = true, name = "CheckInfo")
    var checkInfo: List<CheckInfo> = listOf()
) {
    @Root(name = "CheckInfo", strict = false)
    class CheckInfo(
        @field:Element(name = "CheckNum")
        @param:Element(name = "CheckNum")
        val checkNum: String,
        @field:Element(name = "PaymentDue")
        @param:Element(name = "PaymentDue")
        val paymentDue: String,
        @field:Element(name = "PrintData")
        @param:Element(name = "PrintData")
        var printData: String?,
        @field:Element(name = "CheckEmp")
        @param:Element(name = "CheckEmp")
        var checkEmp: String?,
        @field:Element(name = "OtherInfo")
        @param:Element(name = "OtherInfo")
        var otherInfo: String?,
    )
}
```

The error rise the moment I try to recover this data from the API call which return this kind of data.

So what Am I missing here?

Thank in advance !